# Show these two pavings are the same

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

"Show that if $A \in \mathbb{A}$, then $\mathbb{K}_A = \mathbb{K}$"

I have the following problem, which I have some difficulties solving! I'm not sure if this definition is common or not, so I'll write it along with the problem. Thanks a lot in advance!

A monotone class is a paving $\mathbb{H}$ on $X$ that satisfies the following two conditions: 
\begin{equation}
1) \ \ A_1, A_2,... \in \mathbb{H}, A_1 \subset A_2 \subset ... \Rightarrow \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \in \mathbb{H} \\
2) \ \ A_1, A_2,... \in \mathbb{H}, A_1 \supset A_2 \supset ... \Rightarrow \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n \in \mathbb{H} \\
\end{equation} 
Let $\mathbb{A} \subset \mathbb{H}$ and let $\mathbb{K}$ be the smallest monotone class $\mathbb{K}$ containing all the $\mathbb{A}$-sets.

a) For $A \in \mathbb{K}$ we let 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{K}_A = \{B \in \mathbb{K} | A \cap B \in \mathbb{K}, A \backslash B \in \mathbb{K} \}
\end{equation}
Show that $\mathbb{K}_A$ is a montone class. I've already done this part, so it can be used for the next questions.

b) Show that if $A \in \mathbb{A}$, then $\mathbb{K}_A = \mathbb{K}$

I know I'll have to use the fact that $\mathbb{K} \subset \mathbb{K}_A$ since $\mathbb{K}$ is the smallest monotone class containing all $\mathbb{A}$-sets and by construction $\mathbb{K}_A \subset \mathbb{K}$, so they should be equal IF I can show $\mathbb{K}_A$ is actually containing all $\mathbb{A}$-sets. Am I correct in that conclusion? If so, how do I do this? If not, how do I do it then? :p

This next question is very similar, and help would also be appreciated here:

c) Show that if $A \in \mathbb{K}$, then $\mathbb{K}_A = \mathbb{K}$

Comment: Note that $ \mathcal{A} $ is an algebra